# get object response value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I got a response from the backend the response is an object how can I get the arrays from the object I tried to use `Object entries` but I can't get the arrays can you please help me[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to retrieve just the value part of your object.

Example:

```js
const object = {
  "20-01-22": ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  "21-01-22": ['b', 'c'],
  "22-01-22": ['d', 'f']
};

const arrays = Object.values(object)

// => [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['b', 'c'], ['d', 'f']];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `for`:

Example:

```
const cars = ["BMW", "Volvo", "Saab", "Ford", "Fiat", "Audi"];

let text = "";
for (let i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
  text += cars[i] + "<br>";
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_loop_for